# Create a simple wave with SVG issue

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a simple wave with SVG to put on my website. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
<svg height="100" width="500">
  <path d="M 0 50 
           Q 125 0, 250 50, 375 100, 500 50
           L 500 100
           L 0 100
           L 0 50
           Z" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a5q41t26/

The problem is that I can't align the bottom of the path with the bottom of the lower wave to avoid the gap.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess I've come up with an answer. L 500 75 L 0 75 fixes the issue, however I don't get the logic in this case.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harf9xju/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first coordinate pair, of the two pairs in a `Q` path command, is a control point.  The curve does not pass through the control point.

Have a look at the [section on Quadratic bezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_curves) in Wikipedia.

Comment: Paul, I've just realized that I'm using the Bezier curves. You are right, it makes sence now.